# Why is latent heat of transformation constant in the Clausius Clapeyron Eqn?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

I recently plotted a vapor pressure curve for R134a by graphing logP against 1/RT, covering a temperature range from -36C to 86C (data from source below). This plot, as predicted by the Clausius-Clapeyron Equation, appears to be quite linear, suggesting a roughly constant value for the heat of vaporization, ΔHvap, across this range. However, in the same PT data table I used, there is a column for hfg (the heat of vaporization) that shows ΔHvap actually changing by more than a factor of 2 across the same pressure range. My understanding was that this ΔHvap should directly relate to the slope of my logP vs 1/RT plot.

Can anyone explain this apparent contradiction? Why isn't the heat of vaporization constant as implied by the linearity of the logP vs 1/RT vapor pressure curve?

[R134a Saturation Properties Table]
[1]https://www.ohio.edu/mechanical/thermo/property_tables/R134a/R134a_PresSat.html

Comment: So are the actual data bounded by the Clausius–Clapeyron-predicted curves using the lowest and highest latent heat? Many things look “quite linear” on a log plot.

Comment: The CC-predicted latent heat is similar to the latent heat for T ~ 80 C. The CC equation should indeed be linear on a logP plot.

Comment: The worksheet you linked below indicates that you've applied the ideal-gas assumption. Why? The NIST data don't satisfy this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I guess that you're using the vapour pressure equation
$$
P \propto e^{-L/RT}
$$
where $L$ is the latent heat for the phase transition. This can be derived from the Clausius-Clapeyron relation
$$
\frac{dP}{dT} = \frac{L}{T \Delta V}
$$
under the following assumptions:

1. The latent heat $L$ is constant over the range of temperatures in question.
2. The volume of the other phase is negligible compared the the volume of the gas (i.e., $\Delta V \approx V_g$.)
3. The gas phase can be treated as an ideal gas (so that $P V_g = n R T$.)

But in your case these assumptions (#1, of course, but also #2 and maybe even #3) are violated.  To be more general, we can derive the slope of your graph directly from the Clausius-Clapeyron equation:
$$
\frac{d(\log P)}{d(1/RT)} = - \frac{R T^2}{P} \frac{dP}{dT} = - \frac{L R T}{P(V_g - V_i)}
$$
where $V_i$ is the molar volume of the other phase.  Your table contains all of these values (I think), so you could calculate this quantity over the range of pressures & temperatures and figure out how much the slope "should" vary.  I would not be surprised to find that the variations in $L$ are at least partially compensated for by variations in $V_i$ and by deviations from the ideal gas law.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems like a very big coincidence that by making these three assumptions, we can reproduce the phase boundary almost exactly. The latent heat that fits the phase boundary is ~95 kJ/kg, which is for some reason the experimental value of latent heat at about 80 C. This seems like a random number, with the Tcritical being ~120C.

Comment: My simple plots: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oz5xB5WqID8HvCtGQczljAez5vFng3kpy0cGtEz24dQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'd like to correct my previous comment: the latent heat that fits the phase boundary is actually about 220 kJ/kg, which approaches the experimental value at lower pressures.

Comment: @SamLin: At lower pressures is where I'd expect conditions 2 & 3 to be best satisfied.  As far as #1 goes, I'm not sure.  There's almost certainly some connection between (for example) latent heats and deviations from the ideal gas law, but I'm not well-versed enough in this area of physics to say more than that with any confidence.